# Strange issue with Index Out Of Range Exception in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DGV in a VB.NET(2019) project and I copy the cells at specific row index, but am experiencing a strange issue:

```
    TXTItemDetail.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(1).Value
    TXTOuterpackQTY.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(2).Value
    TXTOuterpackName.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(3).Value
    TXTItemCodeSelected.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(4).Value

    TXTCGST.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(7).Value
    TXTSGST.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(8).Value
    TXTIGST.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(9).Value
    TSSLHSNCode.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(10).Value
    TXTItemCode.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(11).Value

    'Error is thrown at the line below!!
    TXTRate.Text = DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells(5).Value.ToString
```

Note that on the line on which the error is being generated, the cell index is at 5 while the code has already run through on even higher indexes in the earlier lines of code, going up to cell 11. Yet, an out of range error is generated at this instance.
What I could determine was that I need to place the lines of code in sequence of how the cell numbers appear. For example, if I place cell 5 after 4, this error will not be thrown.

I have used this type of code in many places, but never came across this type of an issue. Could it be some kind of threading issue in VB?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any chance that ItemEnteredRow value changes after index 11 before index 5? Or the entire row changes?

Comment: Don't use the same complex expression over and over. You should assign `DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow)` or even `DGVItemSearch.Rows(ItemEnteredRow).Cells` to a variable and then use that variable over and over.

Comment: As for the issue, use your debugger. That's why you have one. Put a breakpoint at the top of the code and then use the Autos, Locals, Watch and Immediate windows to view the values of relevant expressions as you step through the code line by line. You can then see what is changing and what isn't and whether it matches your expectation. It may just be that this project is broken because that does sound strange but the debugger will help you gather as much information as possible. Do you have any other threads? If not, how could it be a threading issue?